# Make Method init once only in after_sign_in_path_for given by devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, salesforce

**More Updates**

Its working if I pull the salesforce method and trigger it in my application controller. Its getting triggered in the `after_sign_in_path_for` method given by devise. This round about is not working because seems like the response coming back from salesforce is failing because its getting sent twice. I am guessing that this method got hit twice when I refresh the page? But I have to init the method after update and this is where the next page is and for now the final page. any ideas to make it init once only?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protect_from_forgery

  def salesforce_add_contact
    client = Databasedotcom::Client.new("config/databasedotcom.yml")
    client.authenticate(:username => "george@thirdmind.com.admsbox", :password => "newD3v13!DotcZyckaLNki3jwKCEfoHfdy" )

    #ruby syntax?
    params = { :PortalID => current_user.id.to_s,
               :firstname => current_user.first_name,
               :lastname => current_user.last_name,
               :email => current_user.email,
               :country_of_residence => current_user.country_of_residence,
               :primary_language => current_user.primary_language,
               :high_school_graduation_year => current_user.high_school_graduation_year}

    params = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(params)
    path = "/services/apexrest/v2/portalAccount"
    result = client.http_post(path, params)
    result = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(result.body)

    # if (result['status'] == "Success")
    #   self.sfdc_contact_id = result['ContactId']
    # end
  end

  def not_found(msg="Not Found")
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new(msg)
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    chooseapplication_path
    #salesforce_add_contact()
  end 

  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :first_name << :last_name << :high_school_graduation_year
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :high_school_graduation_year << :country_of_residence << :primary_language << :password << :password_confirmation
  end
end
```

**Updated**

Maybe the values aren't allowed to be retrieved? I am using devise, but I don't think configuring permitted parameters work for the salesforce method (work on sign in , sign up, update I think)..... also some values did get retrieved inside the salesforce method just not the ones getting updated.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

#Catch all CanCan errors and alert the user of the exception
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do | exception |
    redirect_to root_url, alert: exception.message 
  end

protect_from_forgery

  def not_found(msg="Not Found")
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new(msg)
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    page_path('chooseapplication')
  end 

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    root_url
  end

  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :first_name << :last_name << :high_school_graduation_year << :role << :uid << :provider
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << :first_name << :last_name << :high_school_graduation_year << :role << :uid << :provider << :email << :password
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :high_school_graduation_year << :country_of_residence << :primary_language << :password << :password_confirmation
  end
end
```

---

I have a registrations controller that is inheriting from devise registration.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  #after_action :salesforce_add_contact

  def update
    account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)

    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    if account_update_params[:password].blank?
      puts "entered if statement"
      account_update_params.delete("password")
      account_update_params.delete("password_confirmation")
      puts account_update_params.inspect
    end

    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(account_update_params)
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case their password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
      #salesforce_add_contact()
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource) 
    page_path('verifyemail')
  end 

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    page_path('verifyemail')
  end 

  def salesforce_add_contact
    client = Databasedotcom::Client.new("config/databasedotcom.yml")
    client.authenticate(:username => "secret", :password => "secret" )

    params = { PortalID: current_user.id.to_s,
               firstname: current_user.first_name,
               lastname: current_user.last_name,
               email: current_user.email,
               HS_Grad_Year: current_user.high_school_graduation_year.to_s}
               #country_of_residence: self.country_of_residence,
               #primary_language: self.primary_language }

    params = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(params)
    path = "/services/apexrest/v1/portalAccount"
    result = client.http_post(path, params)
    result = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(result.body)

    # if (result['status'] == "Success")
    #   self.sfdc_contact_id = result['ContactId']
    # end
  end
end
```

The update method posts three new values to the users table into the current user's record.

The salesforce method is suppose to retrieve these values and then push these over to salesforce over the databasedotcom gem. So that means the salesforce method should come after the update method. I am having trouble implementing that.

I tried putting the method in the update at the end of the statements. I tried putting a after_action logic in the controller. I tried some nasty hacks and its not working.

Comment: Are you sure the salesforce method works?

Comment: @SomeGuy what is your reasoning behind it? actually someone else coded it, so I will take your opinion. So far I do see the data getting pushed out to the salesforce api and I am connecting and getting a response too locally in my server.

Comment: I don't know that it works or doesn't, just that adding it to the end of 'update' should work.  So, I asked if it works as the first thing you should check.  If it doesn't work, there are no clever hacks or tricks that will ever get the result you want.  If it does work, we know that whatever your problem is, that's not it.

Comment: @SomeGuy The update method is posting `high_school_graduation`, `country_of_residence`, and `primary_language`. It got committed. When I was pushing thee values (in salesforce method) , they did not show up in the data structure. That is why I asked this question.

Comment: Can you clarify "did not show up in the data structure" ?

Comment: @SomeGuy I mean the value of `current_user.high_school_graduation_year.to_s` inside the `params` inside the salesforcemethod did not show up even though during the update method it got posted and committed.